# Choosing token over session or vice versa?

Tags: authentication, session-management, token, json

I wanted to build a secure user interaction to the server, but I stumbled upon using either token or session. Here are couple of options that I thought about:

1. I learned JWT, built a token, and sent it back and forth between server and client in my local server. Seems like a good thing to do, since using HTTPS, only two parties will be able to communicate in between, therefore quite secure.
2. However, when I looked into the websites like Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, they don't have token, but have session with bunch of variables. I assume they are for authentication.

Which option is a right way to opt? I opt to choose token, as it is secure, I say, why burden server with the load client can handle when you can offload if token is used.

However, I have a feeling that tokens are basically not used in website, but only in APIs.

Answer (score 1):

A token and a session is basically the same thing on a different view. A cookie would be a different thing.

As the HTTP protocol is stateless, the server must have a way to maintain the state of the connection. A session (generally) is a file *stored on the server*, with all the state variables of the client on it. The token is the value send back from the client, so the server knows which file to read. A session and its token are more secure than a cookie because the client cannot change arbitrary fields, and generates less traffic.

A cookie is another approach: it's a file *stored on the client* with all the session data. They store all data of the connection. I don't like cookies because of the overhead of making sure that the client haven't changed any value.

Comment: @Cthulhu, storing data on insecure places will not add security. It's way more secure to keep all data on server, and only a token on client. Never ever blindly trust any data coming from the client. And you will incur on a lot of overhead sanitizing and validating all data from client. And less overhead handling a token.

Comment: @Cthulhu You cannot store the token on the server, the client must send it. Otherwise, how could the server possibly know which client he is talking to?

Comment: @Cthulhu I think this illustrates that you don't know exactly how a session works... If storing a token on the server is insecure, how can a client trust anything coming from it?